# Book recommendations on number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, book-recommendation

I want some good books recommendation on number theory.
I self-studied a good chunk of calculus and I am self-studying analysis right now, and would like to start number theory. I also have a good understanding of mathematical proofs.
So, any recommendations for good advanced books on the topic?

Comment: Possibly too elementary for you: "Elementary Number Theory" (1938) Uspensky and Heaslet.